# Statistical test for the differences of the differences in two proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, proportion

I have four data points:

Proportion A,  N = N_A
Proportion B,  N = N_B
Proportion C,  N = N_C
Proportion D,  N = N_D

I want to know if

(Proportion A - Proportion B)  is significantly different to (Proportion C - Proportion D)

Does anyone know how you test for this?

I know how to do a normal proportions test but feel that that doesn't apply here as i'm looking for a test of the DIFFERENCE OF THE DIFFERENCE between two proportions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same method used for the Wald test for differences in proportions can be applied to your setting.  The standard error of the double difference is $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{4}p_{i}(1-p_{i})/n_{i}}$ which leads to a $z$-test (large-sample test assuming normality).

But beware of the scale.  You would be making a strong assumption that the absolute risk scale is the scale on which the double difference *might* be zero if effects are irrelevant.   This may not be the case.  Frequently we run these types of contrasts on the logit scale and test $H_{0}$: ratio of odds ratios = 1.  This is just the test for interaction in a binary logistic model.